# Unable to access the root directory

Tags: permissions, root

I have started using Openfoam recently. I successfully installed Ubuntu Deb Pack version 2.4.0 but when installing the repository release version 2.4.x, i am unable to access root directory even after using command sudo su -.

I typed Exit unknowningly after accessing in to root directory once. This happened when there was no command prompt present in the terminal. Now I am stuck up in accessing root directory. Please let me know on how to proceed from here.

This is what it shows now,

```
thejes@thejes-ubuntu:~$ sudo su -
Cannot execute exit: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That "exit" you typed was probably inside a file and you saved that. Now it is interfering with normal actions since it is not a command, file or directory. Remember what you did or check with arrow up if you can find a command that gives a hint on what file it is you changed.

Comment: Maybe try `sudo su` (no dash -), that will keep it from being a login shell and it may bypass the borked file.

Comment: +1 ... although I think `sudo -s` would be the preferrred method of invoking a non-login root shell in Ubuntu (cf. `sudo -i` for a root login shell). Another potential get-out-of-jail-free card might be `sudo bash --noprofile --norc`.

Comment: thanks for your comments, by using sudo -s i am able to login the root shell now.